# Is there any way we could add video filters in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming

Can we create a video streaming app in flutter.I am trying to make a video streaming app but can find filters in flutter.

Comment: I think there are packages for that. Also this community helps fix your code, not give suggestions. You can ask suggestions from the official flutter discord group.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is what we call Deep AR that could provide filter for your video just like in Snapchat:

> **DeepAR** is a web platform that provides an SDK for Snapchat kind of 3D
> face filters, face lenses, and effects for any iOS, Android, Unity, or
> HTML5 app. The platform makes use of a technology called **Augmented
> Reality (AR)**.

So you need to setup an account [here](https://developer.deepar.ai/). For a more detailed process on adding filter in your video, you can visit [this blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/easiest-steps-to-build-a-face-filter-app-with-flutter-and-deep-ar-c020037d893d).

For creating livestream alone, check this out: [Live Streaming With Mux, Stream, and Flutter](https://getstream.io/blog/live-streaming-with-mux-stream-and-flutter/)